# Creating my own SSO in android

Tags: android, single-sign-on

I know there are some examples for SSO using fb, but i like to create a parent app which can be used to sign in for all of my child apps; Any idea??
Thanx in advance :)

How to generaye my custom API key for my child apps for using my parent app???

Comment: Why do you need yet another SSO for ? Will it really add something for the user (except a new user/password to remember)? Try to use existing account to avoid user workload, and link your account to the existing one transparently.

Comment: @XGouchet:Thnx for the comment, but i'm trying to reduce the usage of storing and fetching the password from db or shared prefs; coz all of them has an authentication page which has same field(s). any idea wats am i into??

Comment: If you use the AccountManager, you can use an account the user is already logged in, and just make him choose the account you want. Then you can use the account information to sign in / log into your own service

Comment: thnx dude :) didn't even strike b4 u mentioned it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put my comments in an answer :

To avoid workload on the user side, and having to create yet another login/password pair, try using the existing account registered on the device, using the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

The user will only have to select an account he is already logged into, and you can transparently use it to create an account in your service.

Another advice would be too hash and salt the data you're using to avoid sending private data in the clear.

Comment: Agree with AccountManager approach, however hashing and salting data before you are sending buys little security. An attacker could just replay what is sent.  Those techniques are best done just for storage in case the pwd DB is stolen.